# Why are centers, centralizers and normalizers called that way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

I know what they are, but where do the names come from?

Comment: They seem much more meaningful than [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), [Okular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okular), [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX),$\dots$